# No buildable Go Source Files when attempting to go get

Tags: ubuntu, go, gopath

I'm in the process of deploying my go fileserver on an ubuntu server, but when I run go get cms-web-server from my $GOPATH directory, I get the following error:

```
src/cms-web-server/main.go:18:2: no buildable Go source files in $GOPATH/src/github.com/codegangsta/negroni
src/cms-web-server/main.go:19:2: no buildable Go source files in $GOPATH/src/github.com/gorilla/mux
src/cms-web-server/main.go:14:6: no buildable Go source files in $GOPATH/src/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
```

It's weird because it seems like my GOPATH is set correctly. Could there be issues with the packages I'm using?

Comment: judging by the error, there's no files in those directories. Are they empty? Did you fetch them with `go get`?

Comment: @JimB I cloned the files straight from my existing repo that works on my local machine. Those directories definitely have many .go files in them

Comment: So what is your GOPATH set to? And what is actually in that directory?

Comment: Is GOPATH in your repo? If so, are you sure they're checked in, because each of those packages would normally be it's own git repo, in order for `go get` to work.